# Calculating the number of protons in the sun

Tags: homework-and-exercises, protons

The central density of the Sun is ρ = 150 gm/cm<sup>3</sup>. 
Suppose that the center of
the Sun is composed only of free protons with a mass of  1.67 × 10<sup>−24</sup> gm.

What is the number of protons per cm<sup>3</sup> at the Sun’s center?

how would you do this?

Comment: Am I missing something here? Don't you just divide the density by the proton mass?

Comment: @JohnRennie In order to cancel out the masses you must divide one mass by the other. This way you get the number of second masses in the first. Density is something different. Or I am missing something.

Comment: @ValentinTihomirov The units on the mass are grams/proton, so you end up with protons/cm$^3$ after John's calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Let me rephrase your question:

> The (mass to volume) density of a material is $\rho = 10 \frac{\text{g}}{\text{cm}^3}\,$. It is composed by objects with a mass of $m = 1\,\text{g}\,$.
>   Calculate the number (to volume) density of these objects.

As said before, given these two numbers you can calculate the number density, often denoted as $n$, simply by dividing:

$n = \frac{\rho}{m} = \frac{10 \frac{\text{g}}{\text{cm}^3}}{1\,\text{g}} = 10 \frac{1}{\text{cm}^3}$

As you can see the unit of mass cancels out in that process. That way you get the number of objects per $\text{cm}^3$ of the material, nothing more. In particular you don't get the absolute number (as your title suggests) without knowing any volume.

If you do that with your numbers you get the desired result. Simple as that.